# Can't connect to the internet in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, connection

I am new to Ubuntu. I recently put together my own computer and I installed a wireless card in it, but I need to use a CD to install drivers so it is recognized. The problem is, Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to run the CD. I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: What wireless card do you have? Type lspci in terminal and your card should be there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Sorry I didn't even realize you replied, I typed in what you said to and I see a network controller and ethernet controller, neither of which seem to be my wireless card. This is a piece that is attached to the motherboard, by the way.

Comment: Also my wireless card is a PCE-N53 Asus adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is so powerful that it can detect any Wireless card. You don't need to install driver and you are new to linux, so you have to just propery configure it. The reason of you can't install drivers from cd is Ubuntu has .deb package managing system for installing softwares. So .exe (windows Installer ) can't run in ubuntu directly.